# PHP creating a password reset function with html and php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new at PHP I am making a test admin panel and I would like to add a password reset via html and php 5.6

I don't want to have an email method included where the link is sent to someone.

The only items in my users table is
ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, CREATED

I am working with this code snippet to give me some understanding of why and how php is operating on the backend.

In the following code, I am trying to just simply change the username and password for a user, but I am trying to modify this code by removing the check if username is already taken function, as I do not want to insert so I change it to UPDATE. I have root priv, but how would I remove the check username and just update the password? here is code

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php'; 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

// Validate username
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
} else{
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
            } else{
                $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Validate password
if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
    $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
} elseif(strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6){
    $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}

// Validate confirm password
if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
    $confirm_password_err = 'Please confirm password.';     
} else{
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    if($password != $confirm_password){
        $confirm_password_err = 'Password did not match.';
    }
}

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && 
empty($confirm_password_err)){

    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, 
$param_password);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // 
Creates a password hash

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: adminlogin.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Change User password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
    .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Change User password</h2>
    <p>Please fill this form to change user password.</p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" 
method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-
error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?
php echo $username; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-
error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" 
value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 
'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-
control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?>
</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make this a somewhat more specific question, and maybe reduce the code somewhat further? See "[mcve]" and "[ask]". Right now, it feels like _"Here is a bunch of code I have, can you implement some functionality for me?"_, which is not the kind of question SO is made for, exactly.

Comment: i dont want someone to write it, i want to know how to remove the correct pieces so I can make it work the way I want. Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE INTO users` for one thing, that won't work and  you should look up the manual for that function. Checking for errors would have informed you about it. INSERT and UPDATE are two different animals.

Comment: For removal of code, the DEL and Backspace keys have worked quite well for me in the past. On a more serious note, is this your code?

Comment: *"i dont want someone to write it"* - We kind of have no choice, now do we?

Comment: No, this is not my code. I was using a tutorial from tutorialrepublic. about a crud application. But it doesnt explain password resets. I am confused due to my complete newness to php (3rd day in)

Comment: *"I was using a tutorial from tutorialrepublic"* - well, I for one would surely like to see that site and the syntax they used in there, unless you deviated from it, that we don't know because "you" only know that.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php

Comment: I'd say it isn't *just* your newness to PHP, but to programming in general. You can do anything in any language as long as you understand what it is you want to do and understand the steps needed to get from A to B. This is why you should plan on paper first before hacking away at code.

Comment: So - you *did* change the code. There is no UPDATE INTO in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that [tutorial link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php) now that you posted in comments, you didn't follow it **"to a T".**

They have:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employees SET name=?, address=?, salary=? WHERE id=?";
```

and you have:

```
$sql = "UPDATE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

and is not valid syntax for UPDATE.

which should look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username =?, password=? WHERE id =?";
```

and then passing the extra parameter in the binding.

Visit that tutorial again and **follow it** exactly as shown.

Comment: And of course the update should happen *after* the new password is hashed :-)

Comment: Right you are @Jay